# Javascript: addClassName if input is checked and removeClassName if it was un-checked

Tags: javascript, html, input, checkbox, prototypejs

I'm trying to select all the `li` tags of the document and check if it `hasClassName('yes')` so if it has, it will remove it. But I'm having a TypeError: `Object [object HTMLLIElement], has no method 'hasClassName'` **error**.

This is the DOM method:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $(document.body).select('input').each(function(element) {
        element.observe('click', function() {
            init();
        });
        init();
    });

});
```

The previous code will take the init function and check the if there are checked inputs and add them the 'yes' class name, but if I un-check those inputs, the class remains.
This is the function that I'm trying to do dynamic (add and remove class 'yes');

```
function init() {
    $(document.body).select('input').each(function(element) {
        if (element.checked) {
            element.up('li').addClassName('yes');
        } 

        if ($(document.body).select('li').hasClassName('yes')) {
            element.removeClassName('yes');
        }
    })
}
```

Can you help me solving the last part of this function, so the removeclassname method will work? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about the false answer.  Didn't look close enough.  Having said that, you might want to consider using JQuery as it makes these types of operations trivial.

Comment: Look I like jQuery too, but Prototype is a perfectly good framework in its own right.

Comment: Note that `$$('input')` is the same as your "select" setup there.

Comment: @Pointy Agreed.  I'm certainly not bagging on Prototype.  I was just observing how trivial this particular operation is in JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document.body).select('li')` returns a collection, not an element, right?  I would assume you want:

```
    if (element.hasClassName('yes')) {
        element.removeClassName('yes');
    }
```

However, it seems that your logic is flawed -- you are first adding the class if the input is checked, then you are immediately removing it.  Are you missing an `else`?  Maybe something more like:

```
function init() {
    $(document.body).select('input').each(function(element) {
        if (element.checked) {
            element.up('li').addClassName('yes');
        }
        else {
            element.up('li').removeClassName('yes');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Yes but it should, act on load, check on page load if there is a checked element, and assign the 'yes' class to it (or remove if there is no checked elements but they have class 'yes'). But on the same time, in the next code, if there is a click event, if an input is checked, it should add the 'yes' class to the parent li, and if you uncheck an input (checkbox), it should remove the class 'yes'

This is the code that I have used for events observers

Comment: document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $(document.body).select('input').each(function(element) {
        element.observe('click', function() {
            init();
        });
        init();
    });

});

Comment: This one is working, but I had to use element.up().removeClassName('yes') without the element.up('li') - without the li I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a sec - that "select" is going to return an array of elements. The "hasClassName" function is a function on Element directly, not on Array or Enumerable. You're missing an "each()" layer.

```
$$('li').each(function(li) {
  if (li.hasClassName('yes')) li.removeClassName('yes');
});
```

Comment: Check the previous answer:

Yes but it should, act on load, check on page load if there is a checked element, and assign the 'yes' class to it (or remove if there is no checked elements but they have class 'yes'). But on the same time, in the next code, if there is a click event, if an input is checked, it should add the 'yes' class to the parent li, and if you uncheck an input (checkbox), it should remove the class 'yes' This is the code that I have used for events observers –